# Why is Matlab creating a second ghostly instance for my variable?

Tags: matlab, variables, matrix

I'm working on a matlab program where at one point I create a 3x1001 matrix called 'bots'. I checked that Matlab created this matrix correctly, but as soon as Matlab enters a while-loop, there is an extra matrix called 'bots' of dimensions 1x1001 with different doubles in it.

```
...

bots=zeros([3 1001]);
bots(1,:)=botsStartPlace;
bots(2,1:nbBots-1)=botsStartPlace(2:nbBots);
bots(2,nbBots)=length(indexTable);

whos bots % bots      3x1001            24024  double

while(going)

     whos bots    %bots      3x1001            24024  double
                  %bots      1x1001             8008  double 
....
```

Anyone has a clue why matlab is doing this? It's freaking me out! :p

Comment: Interesting... Could you post a minimal working example with this behavior? Also, what version of Matlab are you running?

Comment: Hi, yes, I'm working on a minimal example. And I'm using Matlab R2012a (7.14.0.739), 64 bit (maci64)

Comment: Voting to close given the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22947906/2778484).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem! My bad, there never was a ghost! Matlab had already gone through the loop once and was ordering the 'whos' output of different calls to the function together which gave me the impression that there where multiple instances. Instead I was just accidentally hurting the matrix in the loop and thereby changing it's dimensions! Sorry for your time! :(

Comment: Probably better to delete the question then. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet does not create a "ghostly" instance:

```
bots = zeros(3, 1001);

whos

going = 2;
while (going)
    whos
    going = going - 1;
end
```

The output is:

```
bots       3x1001            24024  double              
going      1x1                   8  double
```

So the problem cannot really come from the `while`-loop itself.

Comment: Yes, I know that but I just don't understand why matlab would have different instances for the same variable. I never encountered such a thing before and don't know where to start searching for an answer, but the problem starts when the code enters the while loop for some odd reason. Do you know of normal cases where matlab would create more than one instance for the same variable? That would be a great start for me to start debugging my program.

Comment: @VincentPeeters are you serious?

Comment: Yes, why? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @VincentPeeters Please try this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve then we can continue debugging.

Comment: Ok, I will create a better example